# alignment issue with my android app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having `alignment issue` with my app.
as of this moment, the layout of my app is on the left side but I want to center it
no matter what I try or set it just wont be on the center of the android device's screen
Below is the layout xml code of my app

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                        android:text="XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/XXX"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:background="#ff777777"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/XXX"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="176dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:background="#ff777777"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                        android:text="XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                        android:text="XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/XXX"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="177dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:background="#ff777777"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/XXX"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="176dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:background="#ff777777"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                        android:text="XXX" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Start" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnExit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="Exit" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply just this properties to all TableRow :

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add weightsum=2 to and add layout_weight=1 to innner

Comment: it is not what he asked